# HtmlAgilityPack - SelectNodes returns nodes in one case, and null in the other (for the same html)?

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I got very simple html page which looks like this:

(index.html):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="white" text="black">
<center><h1>Test</h1></center>
<a href="/a.html">A</a>

<div class="masterWrapper">
<div class="headerWrapper">
<div class="headerLogo">

</div>
</div>
<div class="clear">
</div>
<div class="sliderWrapper">

</div>
<div class="clear">
</div>
<div class="contentWrapper">
<div class="rightColumn">
<h2>
Test <strong class="green">|</strong><strong>Test2</strong>?</h2>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and almost the same subpage:

(a.html):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test2</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="white" text="black">
<center><h1>Test2</h1></center>

<div class="masterWrapper">
<div class="headerWrapper">
<div class="headerLogo">

</div>
</div>
<div class="clear">
</div>
<div class="sliderWrapper">

</div>
<div class="clear">
</div>
<div class="contentWrapper">
<div class="rightColumn">
<h2>
Test <strong class="green">|</strong><strong>Test2</strong>?</h2>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

the only difference here is the lack of `<a href="/a.html">A</a>` in the second page.

I scrape the above (using Abot) and now the weird thing happens, I'm trying to select ALL h2 tags for current page by XPath, like this:

```
page.HtmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h2");
```

If I use the above on "index.html" - it works fine, but if I use the same line to get nodes from "a.html" - it returns NULL. I also tried SelectNodes("h2"), SelectNodes("/h2"), SelectNodes(".//h2") and SelectNodes("./h2") but all return NULL. Inner html return by Abot is the same for both pages (minus the link I mentioned above).

If I use linq instead of XPath, like this:

```
page.HtmlDocument.DocumentNode.DescendantNodes().Where(x => x.Name == tagNameMinusAttribute)
```

it returns correct values on both pages - why doesn't it work with XPath? Is this some bug in HtmlAgilityPack, or is my XPath syntax wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards.

Comment: I tried both HTML snippets and for me both work will both selection techniques. Btw, instead of `DescendantNodes.Where`, you can use `Descendants(name)`

Comment: @jessehouwing:

Sorry for my late response.

As for topic - odd, for me it still doesn't work... perhaps Abot is to blame? (but I doubt that - after all the other method works...).

I will try to write a small test app and test it again.

Could You please tell me, which version of HtmlAgilityPack are You using, and which .NET version are You targeting? 

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tested in a .NET 4.5 app using the latest HTML Agility Pack from NuGet.

Comment: I have the following test project to test this: http://sdrv.ms/1b1TE4T

Comment: @jessehouwing:

Hmmm I don't understand how but - this works with both the solution You posted, as well as with my new test project... I will need to test it with the old project as well... but I know it returned NULL back then... pretty odd.

Thanks for your time and answer.